# Problema formulario web PHP con servidor Godaddy

Tags: php, revisión-de-código

Realice un formulario PHP para una página web, el problema es que cuando agrego la dirección de mi dominio ".com" éste nunca llega a mi bandeja de entrada. He realizado pruebas con mi cuenta de gmail y de outlook, incluso con una cuenta ".com.mx" y con éstas no presento los mismo problemas, mis cuentas de correo y hosting estan en Godaddy. 
¿Cuál es el error dentro de mi código? Espero puedan ayudarme. gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>IKTUM</title>
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redireccionar(){
        window.location='index.php';
    }
    setTimeout('Redireccionar()', 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])&&($_POST['correo']!='')
&&($_POST['mensaje']!='')){
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $correo = $_POST['correo'];
            $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
            //direción de mi correo
            $para = "Correo_web@sitio.com";
            //Contenido del mensaje
            $titulo = "Contacto ";
            $contenido = '<html>
                            <head>
                                <title>' . $titulo . '</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <p>El visitante <strong>' . $nombre .
'</strong> te ha enviado el siguiente mensaje:</p>
                                <p>Mensaje: ' . $mensaje . ' <br><br> Puedes 
ponerte en contacto al email: ' . $correo . '</p>
                                <p>Este mensaje ha sido generado desde la 
página de iktum.com</p> 
                            </body>
                        </html>';
            $encabezado = "MINE-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $encabezado .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $encabezado .= "From: "Sitio web" \r\n";
            $encabezado .= "Reply-To: \r\n";

            $envio = mail($para,$titulo,$contenido,$encabezado);


            if($envio == true){
            }
            else{
                echo "<h1>Se ha presentado un error en el envío del  

email</h1>";
            }


        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>Se ha presentado un error, completa los campos del    
formulario</h1>";
        }
    ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿`MINE` o `MIME`?

Answer (score 1):

Primero, veo algunos problemas en tu código:

```
$encabezado = "MINE-Version: 1.0\r\n"; #Intercambia MINE por MIME
$encabezado = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; #Correcto
```

Y podrías ahorrar unas líneas de código cambiando la sección de enviar con

```
        if(mail($para,$titulo,$contenido,$encabezado)) {
            #En caso de que el correo se envíe
        }else {
            #Error
        }
```

De igual manera, en mi experiencia, GoDaddy siempre ha tenido problemas al querer enviar formularios con mail de PHP, problemas como que no se pueden enviar los correos o que son marcados como SPAM, para evitarlos te recomiendo utilizar y configurar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), es una librería para enviar correos con PHP, orientada a objetos y muy sencilla de utilizar, en el enlace podrás ver varios ejemplos muy útiles.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez es por el mime, cambia el MINE por MIME;

```
 $encabezado = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

Ademas escapa las comillas o intercala por comilla simple `'`:

```
 $encabezado .= "From: \"Sitio web\" \r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el correo se envía, ¿y dices que lo has recibido en otros servicios de correo correctamente? Entonces podría no ser tu código. No se si tendrás el servicio de correo bien configurado. ¿Has enviado correo desde servicios externos a la cuenta que quieres usar? ¿Llegaron?

De cualquier modo, para las pruebas, debes simplificar. Hay que ir descartando posibles errores...

Primero debes comprobar que llegan mensajes a la cuenta. Usa un servicio externo para enviarte un correo. Si funciona. Hay que comprobar que llega desde lo que estas desarrollando. Debes quitar los parámetros opcionales de **mail** (debes usar sólo los 3 primeros). Luego envía un string simple, como "prueba" desde un script que sólo realice el envío. Si llega, puedes agregar parámetros opcionales, formato al mensaje, etc.

Cuando algo no funciona, hay que ir de menos a más.